# Upgrade WSL to Ubuntu Hirsute 21.04 from 20.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I faced during sudo do-release-upgrade this situation:

```
Reading cache
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 6s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Wed Jul 14 08:30:31 2021) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Wed Jul 14 08:30:41 2021) ===
```

and hold in terminal, no further action.

How to fix it and conduct full upgrade?

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR: `apt purge snapd`

I also have a WSL1 system.  Using do-release-upgrade to go from ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 failed in the same way.  I ran across [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/mwt7wh/for_anyone_on_ubuntu_wsl2_trying_to_upgrade_to/gvvvyih?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) which pointed me in the right direction.  Apparently, WSL doesn't like to upgrade snapd for some reason.  I don't use snapd, so I just deleted it.

After removing snapd, I still saw the lspci failure, but it updated almost everything okay.  There was one package which failed: usrmerge, which failed exactly like [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342043/fatal-error-both-lib-udev-hwdb-bin-and-usr-lib-udev-hwdb-bin-exist): `Both /lib/udev/hwdb.bin and /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin exist.` The solution is to delete one of them.  I deleted the older one.

Comment: Beat me to it - I opened up Reddit this morning and that was the first post staring me in the face!  Since the OP mentioned in the comments on my answer that this is a corporate laptop, we *may* not see a response until Monday.  But I'm hopeful that this will resolve the issues.

Comment: This worked for me as well with WSL2 upgrading from `focal`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using WSL1, since `lspci` is failing somewhere during the upgrade.  `/proc` support is a lot more limited under WSL1 than it is under WSL2.

If that's the case, try converting the instance to WSL2 before running the `do-release-upgrade`.

- First, confirm the distribution name, if you don't know it already, with `wsl -l -v`.
- Make sure the instance isn't running via `wsl --terminate <distroname>`.  Confirm that it is stopped after a few minutes with `wsl -l -v` again.
- Back up the instance using `wsl --export <distroname> <filename.tar>`
- Change the WSL version of the instance with `wsl --set-version <distroname> 2`

Try your `sudo do-release-upgrade` again there.  You can always change the version back to WSL1 after that completes.

Remember, unlike the LTS releases, 21.04 is not necessarily tested by Canonical with WSL (and even less of a chance that they've tested WSL1).  So keep a backup of the 20.04 to go back to just in case.

Comment: I have status:

wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The request is not supported.

Winver reports build 1909 so according to my knowledge WSL2 should be supported

Comment: Ah, yes, but only if you've [installed WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps).  Sorry, I made an assumption there.  Have you installed it per those steps?

Comment: I've instralled patch for kernel (don't know how to confirm success, also verify build and revision number.

Naext in this step:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --set-default-version 2
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2

I suspect that this step is not successful

Comment: That's the normal message.  Now, assuming that you've already backed up, try converting your existing instance from v1 to v2 with `wsl --set-version <distroname> 2`

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The request is not supported.

Comment: "The request is not supported" -- Ugh.  Could be a [number of things](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4840).  Do you have another virtualization platform (e.g. VirtualBox or VMWare) installed?  Did the `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart` complete successfully, and did you reboot after it?  Is "Virtual Machine Platform" checked as in [this screenshot](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4840#issuecomment-788955183)?

Comment: This one works well:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1379

Image Version: 10.0.18363.1646

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.

I use actively VirtualBox and have installed VMware Player 15

Comment: Sorry - Layers of the onion.  Now you're likely facing [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4840#issuecomment-753267508).  If you are using an Intel processor (but not yet AMD), then the latest versions of VirtualBox (6.0) and VMWare Workstation (15.5) are able to run under Hyper-V.  But it's possible you'll have to uninstall them, get WSL2 running, then reinstall them to get the Hyper-V support working.  I'm just not sure of the order there.  Note -- If you are on AMD, then you will need a Preview/Insider version of Windows.

Comment: I use i5-7300U, in device manager I've found Microsoft Hyper-V (PCI Server, Virtual Disk Server, Virtual Machine BusProvider, Virtual Infrastructure Provider) also some related network drivers

Comment: I've done two things: remove VMware, turn on HyperV in Windows Features menu.
Current situation:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1646]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The requested operation could not be completed due to a virtual disk system limitation.  Virtual hard disk files must be uncompressed and unencrypted and must not be sparse.

Comment: My SSD is compressed due to corporate policy. Is there a chance to pass to WSL2 anyway ?

Comment: Wow - Your machine really is fighting you on this.  That one's tougher -- AFAIK, that's a hard and fast requirement.  You could ask that question on the [WSL Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues).  The only thing I could think of is (a) backing up to a `tar`, which I assume you've already done, (b) take that tar to another computer if you have one available (perhaps personal?) where you can run WSL2, (c) import it there as a WSL2 instance, (d) upgrade it to 21.04, (e) export it from that computer, (f) import it back on the company one as WSL1 ... Not fun, I know.

Comment: Or you could attach an uncompressed external drive to your company machine, if that's allowed.  Then `--import` it to that location.

Comment: I've found potential reason, I compress some big folders in the past and Canonical folder gathering all wsl's is compressed. Now I'm uncompressing and will retry conversion

Comment: @AdamMierzwiak CodyCreager's answer is, I'm hoping, going to allow you to do the `do-release-upgrade` on WSL1, so I'm planning on deleting this answer at some point in the near future.  If you are still interested in being able to enable WSL2 for another reason and continue to have issues, then let's do a new Question for that investigation.

Comment: Ubuntu is upgraded now to WSL2 but I cannot use network, it does not connect to corporate proxy

Comment: The main reason for going WSL2 was to do the Hirsute upgrade, so is it possible to do that off the corporate network (assuming a laptop?) and then `--set-version 1`?  Alternatively, first do the `--set-version 1` and then try CodyCreager's answer?  Apologies for leading you down this wild goose chase.  Your machine has had so many issues with WSL2 that just weren't anticipated, and it looks like there might have been a simpler solution that I wasn't aware of when we started this.

Comment: So, update was possible and done, last step was to uncompres folder with WSL files and then process went without any warnings to finish. What problem did I faced is network not working, but already in internal yammer there is a post how to handle problem with some Cisco vpn client - till now not works for me , but still fighting